# VLOOKUP not giving me correct data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an Excel workbook with Sheet 1 (which contains a list of all our current items) and Sheet 2 (which contains a few items and the number of units at a specific location).

Sheet 1:
Item | Description | Units
-- 380 rows

Sheet 2:
Item | Description | Units
-- 48 rows

In Sheet 1, the units column should compare the item name from Sheet 2 and return the number of units from Sheet 2.

**My Formula :**
=VLOOKUP(A5,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$C$48,3)

**Result :**
If the item is not listed in Sheet 2, then the cell in Sheet 1 returns the value from the previous cell in Sheet 1. It should return 0 or blank(NULL)

Is the formula wrong or should I add a IF ISNULL part outside the VLOOKUP function? What would be the correct syntax for it please?

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A5,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$C$48,3,FALSE)` - include the `FALSE` (or a 0)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change your vlookup like so:

```
:=VLOOKUP(A5,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$C$48,3,0)
```

The zero drives an exact match. I never leave that argument indeterminate even though it is optional.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed my code and it worked.
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A5,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$C$48,3,0),"")